# Truncate label on smaller screens, while keeping input position on bigger screens

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to implement the example shown on the images below, preferably using flexbox.

The trouble is that the value `0` on the images should always be visible, while the label may be truncated by `...` on smaller screens.

When there is enough width, the value must still be right next to the label.

[image: small screen]
[image: large screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```css
.flex {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}


.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  background: #f3f5f7;
}

.large {
  width: 400px;
}

.small {
  width: 100px;
}

label {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


div > * {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">

<div class="row large">
  <label>
    loooooong label:
  </label>
  <span>100</span>
  <span class="flex"></span>
  <span>></span>
</div>
  
<div class="flex row small">
  <label>
    loooooong label:
  </label>
  <span>100</span>
  <span class="flex"></span>
  <span>></span>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a standard text-overflow property and wrap your label/input in a flex-div.

[Here's a Pen with two examples.](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/dPWBgO?editors=110)

You can use Media Queries to change this up based on screen sizes. Please note that this is only an example you can use an make better to your specific situation.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label for="value">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong label:</label>
  <input type="text" id="value" name="value" placeholder="0">
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  display: flex;
}
label {
  max-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```